# How to input complex equations in matlab?

Tags: matlab, dft

I am working with DCDFT, Date Compensated DFT. I am relatively new to MATLAB, and as such, I am having problem with initializing some complex variables and input such equations. The inializing statement and the subsequent equations are given as follows:

[image]

[image]

etc.

The code in the MATLAB and the subsequent message is as follows:

[image]

In case anyone wants to see the original code, this is as follows:

> x=xlsread('value.xlsx');
>       t=xlsread ('time.xlsx');
>           N=size(x,1);
>       L=size(t,1);
>       a_0^(-2)=N

The error message is

> Error: The expression to the left of the equal sign is not a valid target for an assignment.

Comment: Post a code with a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Also, note that (sadly) this site does not support LaTeX

Comment: The first equation is equal to N. So it would be helpful if someone could edit it. The Latex equation is $ a_{0}^{-2}=N$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Corrected

Comment: Please show the exact matlab code that produces this error, we cannot help you without that ...

Comment: For the love of all that is MATLAB and holy, please **post actual code**.  Do not post an image.

Comment: I posted the image because it contains my actual code as well as the error message!

Comment: pls, at least have a look at http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html to know how to convert your problem into Matlab language. And then you can read more at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/discrete-fourier-transform-dft.html for DFT in Matlab, so you can have a better overview and accelerate your approach.

Comment: come back and ask again once you know how to make Matlab understand what you meant with `a_0^(-2)=N`

Comment: MATLAB (and pretty much **most** programming languages) assign values to variables (`x = ... `, `y = ...`)  What you are doing is not only assigning to a variable but trying to simultaneously perform an operation on that variable, which is not allowed.  The error message is pretty clear, and a simple search engine query will tell you why.  One thing you can do is temporarily store **the square** of `a_0` and `a_1` then perform the inverse square of the result to get what you want.